# Different reputation for same time frame

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

When I click my Envelope icon it says:

Showing 2009-08-03 to 2009-08-03  ... 182 reputation earned.

When I click the 'Today' button from that is shows:

Showing 2009-08-03 to 2009-08-03 ... 202 reputation Earned.

This repeats if I go back and forth between them.

So why are they different, and since I have only got 5 points from 3 upvotes, I assume I should go with Today regarding the rep cap, is that right?

Comment: Don't mean to cry bug, I might be missing something, but the tag seemed to apply.

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug, but the notification thing violates the principle of least surprise all the time.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait. It's *least* surprise? I thought it was supposed to be *most* surprise. You know, **exciting outside-the-box** software!

Comment: @Welbog: "You searched for 'C++ Boost'.  Here is a video of a llama eating carrots, set to the theme from *The Benny Hill Show*.

Comment: @Pesto: Make a llama angry and you will discover the true meaning of "Boost".

Comment: @mmyers: The true meaning of "Boost" is "Help!  Someone stop this llama from biting me!"?

Comment: No, llamas would rather kick you into orbit. Or spit on you. Either way, you won't be touching the ground a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try now; we clarified the dates and ranges and fixed a really nasty accidental localization of time bug.

Comment: Yup, that makes it clearer.  I think I would like it more if clicking the envelope just went straight to the 'today' view, but I am sure you know more of what is going on than I do... :-)

Answer (score 3):

There's a bug - the envelope icon shows "today from *local* midnight with respect to the server". The "today" button shows "today from UTC midnight."

(At least, I reckon it's a bug - if it's by design then it's an odd design :)

Comment: Always Click on 'Today' to see what is counting towards the Rep Cap.

Comment: @Chacha102: Or use my Rep Tracker :) http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx

Comment: +1 for *it's an odd design*

Comment: @Jon Skeet, on RepTracker, the `yesterday` label tag's `for` attribute should be "YesterdayMode", instead of "Yesterday". Right now it doesn't select the radio button when we click on the label. Thought I'd report that little bug here :)

Comment: Thanks - will fix it soon, if I remember :) I need to look at it all again actually, to allow Stack Exchange sites to be included.